# matplotlib.pyplot import failed in ipython but works in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, dll

I get this long error when i try importing pyplot in ipython. Everything works fine when i try the same in jupyter notebook.
I think I've tried all the suggestions I found about pyplot import errors. I tried reinstalling matplotlib, ipykernel, zmq etc etc., I tried rolling back to old versions. I've tried matching sys.path from notebook and my ipython kernel, but no success.

I'm using python 3.7, windows 10, ConEmu for ipython kernel.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-02aaac1810fb> in <module>
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
   2347     dict.__setitem__(rcParams, "backend", rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
   2348 # Set up the backend.
-> 2349 switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
   2350
   2351 # Just to be safe.  Interactive mode can be turned on without

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in switch_backend(newbackend)
    219         else "matplotlib.backends.backend_{}".format(newbackend.lower()))
    220
--> 221     backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
    222     Backend = type(
    223         "Backend", (matplotlib.backends._Backend,), vars(backend_mod))

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128
    129

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py in <module>
      1 from . import _backend_tk
----> 2 from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
      3 from ._backend_tk import (
      4     _BackendTk, FigureCanvasTk, FigureManagerTk, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
      5

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in <module>
     43
     44 if _has_pil:
---> 45     from PIL import Image
     46
     47 backend_version = 'v2.2'

C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>
     93     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     94     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 95     from . import _imaging as core
     96
     97     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: You have two different pythons installed, one in `C:\Users\chattdip\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` and one in `C:\ProgramData\Python3\Continuum\anaconda3`, and they get mixed up. Make sure to work within a single environment.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the reply. I did seem to have an unknown python in Appdata directory which I completely removed, but it doesn't resolve the issue. I don't see any reference to Appdata anymore but other than that the error is exactly the same.

Comment: It can't be the same, if `AppData` doesn't exist any more. Feel free to update the question with the new error.

Comment: Updated the error.

Comment: This looks like you have a broken pillow version installed. (Matplotlib assumes that either no pillow is installed, or pillow is working correctly). Check what happens if you try to import pillow, like `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had to force re-install pillow. Not sure what changed, but seems to be working now. Strange!